# Hiding description part of item in description environment

Tags: description

How can one hide/display *all* descriptions in a `description` environment at the same time.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Keep This] Discard This
\item[Keep This] Discard This
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not clear what your question is really, you just have one `begin` `end` pair around each answer, so given latex syntax that's "normal" rather than "painstaking" isn't it? What markup do you want?

Comment: You may have to consider capturing the contents between `\item` and another `\item` (with special care taken for the last one). However, how do you handle `[A]` and `[B]` in the above case? Do you include both the *problem* and the *answer* in the same `\item`? Perhaps we need to see a more comprehensive example...

Comment: [A] and [B] should always be there, whereas the answers should selectively be there. One option (perhaps?) would be a modified description environment where item labels are always visible, but the items themselves can be selectively (as a group!) hidden or displayed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in the same way a description environment simplifies writing a typical list of items and their description, I'm sure an environment exists or can be created to do precisely the same thing where the descriptions can be hidden en masse...

Comment: @Henry: Do you have anything following `[A]` or `[B]` that does not belong inside the `answer` environment?

Comment: @Werner no never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to redefine the way `description` works, capturing all its `\item[<stuff>]` content and disregarding *everything* else. This catch-and-release is possible through a local redefinition of `\item` and placing the entire environment inside a box. That way things are not set to the page, but you can process the environment.

The above brief discussion is implemented below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\olddescription\description% Store \description (\begin{description})
\let\endolddescription\enddescription% Store \enddescription (\end{description})
\newsavebox{\descriptionbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\discarddescription}{%
  \renewenvironment{description}
    {\gdef\descriptionlist{}% Clear description list
     \begingroup% Begin local scope
     \def\item[####1]{\g@addto@macro\descriptionlist{\item[####1]}}% Redefine \item[.] to capture its argument
                                                                   % and store it in \descriptionlist
     \begin{lrbox}{\descriptionbox}}% Start capturing elements
    {\end{lrbox}% End capturing elements
     \endgroup% Close local scope
     \begin{olddescription}\descriptionlist\end{olddescription}}% Set captured items in regular description
}
\newcommand{\restoredescription}{%
  \let\description\olddescription% Restore \description (\begin{description})
  \let\enddescription\endolddescription% Restore \enddescription (\end{description})
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Keep this] Definitely keep this
  \item[Keep that] Definitely keep that
\end{description}

\discarddescription

\begin{description}
  \item[Keep this] Discard this
  \item[Keep that] Discard that
\end{description}

\restoredescription

\begin{description}
  \item[Keep this] Definitely keep this
  \item[Keep that] Definitely keep that
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Switches are provided to discard `description` content (via `\discarddescription`) and restore its original functionality (via `\restoredescription`).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to completely hide *all* `description` environments you can simply redefine the `description` environment to ignore anything in its body via [the `environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). So with `\RenewEnviron{description}{}{}`: you obtain:

[image]

If you still want the `\item` labels form the `description` environments then you can hide the `answer` environment in the same manner via `\RenewEnviron{answer}{}`:

[image]

Then, when you want the `ansers` you can use `\NewEnviron{answer}{\BODY}` to obtain:

[image]

### Code: Hide `description` environment

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{comment}

%\excludecomment{answer}
\includecomment{answer}

\RenewEnviron{description}{}{}

\begin{document}
Some text before.
\begin{description}
\item[A]
    \begin{answer}
    Answer A
    \end{answer}
\item[B]
    \begin{answer}
    Answer B
    \end{answer}
\end{description}
Some text after.
\end{document}
```

### Code: Hide `answer` environment

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{answer}{}%       <--- Use this to hide the answer environment
%\NewEnviron{answer}{\BODY}% <--- Use this if you want the answer environment

\begin{document}
Some text before.
\begin{description}
\item[A]
    \begin{answer}
    Answer A
    \end{answer}
\item[B]
    \begin{answer}
    Answer B
    \end{answer}
\end{description}
Some text after.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I may have been unclear - I want [A] and [B] labels to remain (so a list of bold A, B, ... should be the result).

Comment: @Henry: As you still want the labels, I have updated solution to hide _just_ the `answer` environment.

Comment: I'm sorry ok I'm going to update my question to be as clear as possible on this one!!

Comment: please see my updated question. The 'answer' environment was just my attempt (I tried to show my approach, but really I should have started with just my original problem).

Comment: @Henry: The alternate solution (which does not use the `comment` pacakge) already provides for this (but does requite the `\item` content to be an environment).

Answer (score 2):

You can switch easily between different definitions of a command, added a % and deleting another one. I do this a lot, to change layout. Think of your tex document as a kind of database, keeping as much formatting information as possible in the header.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%\newcommand*{\thing}[2]{\item[#1] #2}
\newcommand*{\thing}[2]{\item[#1]}

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
\thing{A}{A}
\thing{B}{B}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This exploits the fact that in a `description` one *has* to specify the optional argument. It's better to give personal environments a name different from the generic one anyway, so I defined an `answers` environment; each item is introduced by `\answer`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifshowanswers
%\showanswerstrue % uncomment for showing answers

\NewEnviron{answers}{%
  \begin{description}
  \ifshowanswers
    \let\answer\item
    \BODY
  \else
    \expandafter\processitems\BODY\answer\processitems
  \fi
  \end{description}
}

\makeatletter
\long\def\processitems\answer[#1]#2\answer#3\processitems{%
  \item[#1]%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\processitems\answer#3\processitems}% restart the recursion
}

\begin{document}

\begin{answers}
\answer[A] Discard answer text A
\answer[B] Discard answer text B
\end{answers}

% this is by way of example
\showanswerstrue

\begin{answers}
\answer[A] Discard answer text A
\answer[B] Discard answer text B
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an incredibly good answer, unfortunately I don't feel qualified to judge which one of the several is the 'best'. Thank you!